# Looping object arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to loop all my arrays inside a object and then check if the object inside the array has a imageUrl set, if not. Then set it to default.

portfolio[i] returns undefined.

```
that.portfolio = {
     applications = [
         { imageUrl: "" }
     ],
     websites = [
         { imageUrl: "" }
     ]
}

var setDefaultImage = function () {
                var portfolio = that.portfolio;
                var defaultImageUrl = "App/Main/images/shared/defaultImg64x64.png";

                for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(portfolio).length; i++)
                    portfolio[i].forEach(function (currentObj) {
                        if (!currentObj.imageUrl) {
                            currentObj.imageUrl = defaultImageUrl;
                        }
                    });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`portfolio` is an object not an array, so correct way to loop it would be `for-in` loop:

```
for (var key in portfolio) {
    portfolio[key].forEach(function(currentObj) {
        if (!currentObj.imageUrl) {
            currentObj.imageUrl = defaultImageUrl;
        }    
    });
}
```

As you can see, no need to overthink here with `Object.keys(portfolio)` however you can use it too if you want:

```
var keys = Object.keys(portfolio);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    portfolio[keys[i]].forEach(function (currentObj) {
        if (!currentObj.imageUrl) {
            currentObj.imageUrl = defaultImageUrl;
        }
    });    
}
```